# Drupal gets HTTP Result Code: 403 when try to change title of view to <none>

Tags: gridview, view, drupal-7

I can't change the title of a drupal view to none. Some views already have title none but I can't change the title of some others. The view that I am having this error has a grid format.
This is the error I get:

> ```
> An AJAX HTTP error occurred.
> HTTP Result Code: 403
> Debugging information follows.
> Path: https://covid-19-charts.ca/admin/structure/views/ajax/display/charts/block_1/title
> StatusText: Forbidden
> ResponseText: 
> 403 Forbidden
> 403
> Forbidden
> Access to this resource on the server is denied!
> Proudly powered by  LiteSpeed Web ServerPlease be advised that LiteSpeed Technologies Inc. is not a web hosting company and, as such, has no control over content found on this site.
> ```

After a few of these errors I got a security warning to which I had to reply that I was not a robot!

Comment: You have this error only with 'none' or any changes tried ?

Comment: Only 'none'. Other changes work.

Comment: It's probably a required value , so you cannot empty this field , perhaps you can display none on front , in templating process ?

Comment: 'None' is a common field and the instruction gives that option for the title.

Comment: I couldn't enter the less and greater signs into the text (perhaps there is a way of doing it but I didn't know). It should be "less" none "greater"

Comment: Can you see something into dblog errors to get more details about error  ?

Comment: I got blocked out of my server trying to identify the problem. I got a number of errors and am not sure which are related to the view problem but some are: Content Security Policy: Ignoring “'unsafe-inline'” within script-src: ‘strict-dynamic’ specified
Content Security Policy: Ignoring “https:” within script-src: ‘strict-dynamic’ specified
Content Security Policy: Ignoring “http:” within script-src: ‘strict-dynamic’ specified

Comment: My server support whitelisted my IP and that let me back in AND it allowed me to fix this problem ... i.e. I was able to change the title to <none>.) Is that a clue to the original problem? I don't to have to be whitelisted again,

Comment: You have to check your server if firewall accept all IP or just several IP , if you manage to save with an IP whitelisted you have a configuration to review on your server , not in drupal

Comment: I think the problem is with Drupal ... only that particular view update has a problem.

Comment: My host replied with this: Your connection was blocked due to the "XSS vulnerability in the Node Access Product module for Drupal (CVE-2015-3386)". Please check the link below:
https://cve.mitre.org/cgi-bin/cvename.cgi?name=CVE-2015-3386

Comment: Your drupal have last core version or still to oldest ?

Comment: I have 7.78 installed (I always update to the most recent)